# CoCreateGuid compilation -undefined-reference when using codeblocks

Tags: c++, guid, undefined-reference

I am in need to create a GUID - used `CoCreateGuid(&guid)`  and the output in string form to be returned. I have used CodeBlocks GNU GCC compiler and the compiler reports error "Undefined reference to CoCreateGuid@4". Not able to resolve even after web search and several attempts.
`#include <rpc.h>`, `#include <objbase.h>`, `#pragma comment(lib,"ole32.lib")`, `#pragma comment(lib,"rpcrt4.lib")` have been included. What should I do to clear the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `#pragma` functionality is compiler-dependent. Does your compiler support adding linker libraries with a pragma, opposed to passing the linker library via linker option?

Comment: Yes, both linker libraries supported. I am not able to find the rpcrt4.lib to include in the linker option. Hence i tried to add. Compiler accepted.

Comment: "_Yes, both linker libraries supported._" Not what I asked. I asked whether linking linker libraries via `#pragma` is supported by your compiler. Since if it's not - those lines are ignored, and libraries are not linked in.